# Replacing custom field with shortcode

Tags: custom-field, shortcode

I've been using custom fields for my wordpress theme, but i'd like to use shortcodes now for easier posting.

so before, in my index.php i have this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Thumbnail", true);?>
```

how do i replace it with custom fields? SUch that i can just insert:

```
[thumbnail]http://domain.com/image.jpg[/thumbnail]
```

Answer (score 1):

A shortcode like this

```
[thumbnail height=100 width=100]http://urltoimage.com/image.jpg[/thumbnail]
```

Would need this type of setup

```
function content_insert_thumbnail($atts, $content = null){
    global $post;
    extract($atts);
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array($height, $width));
    $content .= $thumbnail; //Places the thumbnail after the content
    return $content; //Never echo a value from a shortcode function.
}
add_shortcode('thumbnail', 'content_insert_thumbnail');
```

To call this in your theme to insert your thumbnail:

```
$atts = array(
    'height' => 100,
    'width' => 100
);
content_insert_thumbnail($atts);
```

This example doesn't make sense to place in your theme as you can just call the_post_thumbnail() function. However, this example is just to show you how to access the shortcode function (whatever it may be) in your template files.

Comment: how do u call this shortcode for my theme's index.php?

Comment: Just added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will work or not, but just try this code

```
function customfield_shortcode(){
 echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Thumbnail", true);
//instead echo use return
}
add_shortcode( 'thumbnail', 'customfield_shortcode' );
```